# Listen to Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) packet

Tags: mobile-network

Can an Android application generate or listen to ARP packet without root privilege ?

Thank!

Comment: What is your goal?  Do you want to read packets?  In that case, use `tcpdump` with adb shell.

Comment: Yes. I want to read or generate ARP packets. Thanks for your advice :D

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward I need an android lib, which can do that job not adb shell